How to mount an Canon EOS camera?
I have a Canon EOS camera. Since I updated my mac mini to Sequoia, the Canon EOS utility that I use to download the images stopped working. I'm not very confident that Canon will come with an update soon.
By googling a bit, I found out about the Image Caputure app, which I can actually use to download the images. But in order to download and organize the images with a script, it would be very useful if I could somehow 'mount' the camera. Given that Image Capture can communicate with the camera, I'd hope this is somehow possible, but I have no clue how (when running diskutil list, the camera does not seem to show up).
So my question is, can I mount my camera, and if so, how do I do this?

Can't you just take the SD Card (or whatever your camera uses) and put that into a reader connected to your Mac?

In the past, that isn’t how that app works. You copy the files to the Mac, then arrange them. Based on settings you let IC leave the camera alone or delete after import. Documentation indicates that’s your method still.

@nohillside I'd have to buy one for that purpose only, so I'd prefer a software solution if possible

@bmike It seems the link you provided means that mounting is not possible then.

That’s my understanding. I don’t have a camera body to test, though.

For what a reader costs, seems easy enough.

What is the specific model camera?

@SteveM it's an Canon EOS 5D Mark II

Image Capture is using PTP or similar, Canon and Nikon don‘t expose a mountable share via USB.

@nohillside good to know, thanks.
